# React/dotnetcore 3.1 mvc app deployed to IIS 7.5 server loads correctly, but javascript calls to API each return index.html

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, .net-core

My guess is I am dealing with an IIS routing issue.

I have a React/dotnet core 3.1 application that I am developing in Visual Studio. When loaded, the React app attempts to call a REST service in the application to pull in data for a select component (the select component is a drop-down of companies).

All works well in the development environment. When I deploy to a staging server, all API calls are redirected to index.html and I never get the data I was expecting.

My best guess is I have misconfigured routing in my IIS 7.5 server and it does not know how to handle calls to "/api/"

appsettings.json:

```
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
            "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*",
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        DATA REMOVED HERE
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args)
            .Build()
            .Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
        });



        // DI
        services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(this.Configuration);

        /*services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
        });*/

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

- The URL of the main app is: `http://vmsaudit.esdev2.elwood.local`
- The API Call URL of the server is:
  `http://vmsaudit.esdev2.elwood.local/api/Company/er`

Here is the code to my Company Controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CompanyController
{
    VMSImportEngineContext db;
    ErecruitContext erdb;
    IConfiguration config;

    public CompanyController (VMSImportEngineContext db, ErecruitContext erdb, IConfiguration config)
    {
        this.db = db;
        this.erdb = erdb;
        this.config = config;
    }

    [HttpGet("{datastore}")]
    public List<Company> Get(string datastore)
    {
        List<Company> ret = new List<Company>();
        if ("ss".Equals(datastore))
        {
            List<int?> vmsClients = db.VmsClient
                .Where(c => c.legacyID != null && c.audit == true)
                .Select(c => c.legacyID)
                .ToList();

            ret = this.GetSSCompanies(vmsClients);
        }
        else // Has to be ERecruit client
        {
            List<int> vmsClients = db.VmsClient
                .Where(c => c.audit == true)
                .Select(c => c.clientid)
                .ToList();

            ret = this.erdb
                .Company
                .Where(c => vmsClients.Contains(c.company_id))
                .ToList();
        }

        return ret; 
    }

    private List<Company> GetSSCompanies(List<int?> vmsClients)
    {
        List<Company> ret = new List<Company>();
        // Generate a linked query
        string connectionString = this.config.GetConnectionString("vmsimportengine");
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        if (connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            connection.Open();
        }
        DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = GenSSCompanyQuery(vmsClients);
        DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Company company = GetCompanyFromDataRow(reader);
            ret.Add(company);
        }
        return ret;
    }


    private Company GetCompanyFromDataRow(DbDataReader reader)
    {
        Company c = new Company();
        if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("name")))
        {
            c.name = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("name"));
        }
        if (!reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("company_component_id")))
        {
            int cid = (int)reader.GetDouble(reader.GetOrdinal("company_component_id"));
            // now get the real ID from the current system...
            List<int> potential = this.db.VmsClient
                .Where(c => c.legacyID == cid)
                .Select(c => c.clientid)
                .ToList();
            if (potential.Count > 0)
            {
                c.company_id = potential[0];
            }
        }
        return c;
    }

    private string GenSSCompanyQuery(List<int?> vmsClients)
    {
        // Code Suppressed
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I decided to add a new method to my controller and that method appears to be returning data... My issue apparently is with passing a parameter on the end of the API URL call??? Here is the method I just added to my controller which successfully returns "pong"

```
    [HttpGet]
    public string ping()
    {
        return "pong";
    }
```

In summary:

- This API URL Works - http://vmsaudit.esdev2.elwood.local/api/Company
- This API URL does not - http://vmsaudit.esdev2.elwood.local/api/Company/ss

The only difference is the parameter on the end of the URL

Comment: How you have deployed it in IIS? In the root of the Default Web Site or any Virtual Directory under the site. If you have used the Virtual Directory then you need to set the base path like this app.UsePathBase("IISHostVirtualDirPath") in your Startup.Configure.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have not used a virtual directory. It is its own web site with files being served right from the root directory. The URL to the site is: ```http://vmsaudit.esdev2.elwood.local```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a database connection. The authentication credentials for the application pool I was using was incorrect. The result was all REST service calls that used the connection returned the index.html page. I assume this is because the Entity Framework code threw an exception in startup and the routing code was never reached?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of potential issues in your code. Nobody will tell you for sure what is wrong, but you can try to play with some settings.

1. Try to comment this line in your startup.cs. Better, use HTTPS redirect on IIS side. Your app is running on Kestrel server which is running behind IIS, so if SSL is not set up on IIS, your app will die silently with some cryptic error, like **site cannot be reached**.

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

2. In production, you're supposed to build React project yourself, maybe you forgot to do this. For testing purposes, try to comment all lines like below or set environment in your appsettings.json to DEVELOPMENT. In this case you can try to check if your app is running the same way in production as it does on your local computer.

```
env.IsDevelopment()
```

3. To avoid CORS issues, try to allow not only all hosts, but all headers and methods

```
builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod()
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1

4. By default, Kestrel server accepts requests only from localhost. When you deploy it to production server, you may need to allow requests coming from specific IP, or from all IPs on specific ports.

```
"Kestrel": {
  "EndPoints": {
    "Http": {
      "Url": "http://0.0.0.0:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

For detailed guide of how to fix other potential issues with IIS, check this answer.

https://superuser.com/questions/1514511/iis-is-not-accessible-remotely-on-vps-hosting