# How can I deploy an ASP.NET Web API with React frontend to IIS?

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, iis, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to deploy my react app with a .NET Web API backend to IIS. In order to get the react app to show up I add the "homepage" property to my package.json for example "homepage": "/testapp/". The client app works and routes properly but any requests to the api just return the react app again instead of json data. When I launch the app locally in Visual Studio using IIS Express everything works fine. When I deploy the app all of api my routes for example /testapp/api/logs no longer return data (/api/logs returns 404). Does anyone have any insight on how to handle client side vs back end routing when deploying to IIS?

Comment: Does the backend in IIS return data?

Comment: Be sure you have updated the local backend URL in the react app to the URL of the backend on the server

Comment: It was an authentication issue. I was led down the right path by this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59954754/react-dotnetcore-3-1-mvc-app-deployed-to-iis-7-5-server-loads-correctly-but-jav. But in my case it wasnt the application identity pool, I just needed to change the authentication for the site in IIS from anonymous to windows authentication.

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue with the connection to the data string. I added a test controller and found that the api was returning static data successfully. When it tried to hit the database it would return the index.html as an exception. I changed my site's authentication in IIS from anonymous to windows authentication and now my API returns data.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 There are fundamental differences you should be aware of. Windows authentication might help but not always is the right solution. You should see if using a proper application pool identity is better.